# Does Hibernate envers provide information on which user made a change on what time

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

Does Hibernate envers provide information on which user(who) made a change on what time(when)

e.g. A user could change join_date and address information (say city, zipcode). I would expect envers to tell me what fields were modified to what values.

```
user
----
id     join_date      Address      Zipcode
-------------------------------------------
1      2-02-2010       Dublin       94568
```

Recently updated records should be

```
id   Item       Event      Changed_to    Modified_at       Admin
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1    join_date  update     2-2-2008      10 hours ago      john@example.com
```

Comment: Unless you explicitly provide the users information, envers will not log it.

Answer (score 2):

Envers has no way of knowing what's a "user" in your system. You can create a custom revision entity as described [in the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-revisionlog), and add the appropriate fields there.

Each revision by default has a timestamp.